# Green's formulae, Stokes theorem, Gauss theorem, divergence theorem and Gauss-Green theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, reference-request, vector-analysis

I am getting really confused about the Green's formulae, the Divergence theorem and all those related equalities.

For example, How is this formula exactly called?

$$\int_\Omega \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j} v \, dx = - \int_\Omega u \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j} \, dx + \int_{\partial \Omega} uv \nu_j dS  \quad \quad \boldsymbol{(1)}$$

Is this Divergence theorem? I have seen it called Green-Gauss formula, but searching on Google does not yield relevant results.

On the other hand,

$$\int_{\Omega}v \Delta u \  (d\Omega) =\int_{\partial \Omega}v  (\nabla u )\vec{n} \   d (\partial \Omega) - \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v \  (d \Omega) \quad \quad \quad \boldsymbol{(2)}$$

What about this formula? This one seems to be called Green's first identity.

> Is there any good reference where **all** these results are preciselly stated and **named**?

I could provide more equalities but I think you get the point. For example:

$$\int_{\Omega}(\nabla\cdot u)d(\Omega)=\int_{\partial \Omega} u \cdot \vec{n}\ d (\partial \Omega) \quad \quad \quad \boldsymbol{(3)}$$

Is this generalized Divergence Theorem?

Comment: All of these relationships are effectively integration by parts.  In fact, one can prove Stokes' Theorem using coordinate transformation and Green's Theorem in the plane.

Comment: I've been told that the naming conventions changed over the last century, but no one really seems to care what they're called. A place to find all these things that might have some standard names would be the appendix of Evans' PDE.

Comment: @StanCoreyCarter Thank you, that helped. Now I have red calculus appendix from Evans' PDE it is more clear.